# SQL Server: return joined data from insert select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I perform steps:

1. Create temporal table and fill it with data and unique order column `[_oid]`
2. Insert everything from temporal table into real table except fictional `[_oid]`, outputting generated `[id]`'s
3. Return those generated `[id]`'s along with corresponding `[_oid]`

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    [Hash] INT NOT NULL,
    [Size] INT NOT NULL,
    [Data] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [_oid] INT NOT NULL
)

--here insert data into #temp--
INSERT [dbo].[TestObjects]
OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id]
    SELECT [Hash], [Size], [Data] 
    FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

How I can return `([Id], [_oid])` rows ? ....Or at least return `[Id]` ordered by `[_oid]` ?

I know insert does not preserve order of inserted items in it's output, but still...

Comment: in order to add to your OUTPUT a field from the source table, you must use MERGE. search SO around, plenty of posts about that

Comment: Ummm, is MERGE the only way? I'm only inserting values, not updating, nor deleting them. Does it have impacts on performance in insert-only scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I think you what you are asking for is INSERT INTO, as so:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestObjects]
SELECT Hash, Size, Data FROM #temp
ORDER BY _oid
```

But as you say, there's no guarantee about order when you select from TestObjects, so if it's important can you not have a field in TestObjects you can ORDER BY when you SELECT from it?

Comment: And how do I get generated ids order by _oid?

Answer (score 1):

IF your insert into #temp is such that both o_id and (hash,size,data) are unique for each row (ie keys), then you could retrieve the inserted o_id from #temp:

```
select t.[_oid],to.[Id]
from #temp t
inner join [dbo].[TestObjects] to 
on t.Hash=to.Hash and t.Size=to.Size and  t.data=to.data
```

Comment: No, this code is generated, so no - second part is not unique in general.

Comment: What is the use of showing for each Id which _oid caused its creation, if there is another _oid that caused the creation of another Id with the same data? Even if there is, obviously this can only be done with merge/output.

Comment: It is EF6 integration upon bulk insert. Story short - I need to preserve order of inserted and generated values in request, so I can correctly integrate with EF entities. One way is to provide order _oid which is basically for cicle generated to preserve order later one.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by George Menoutis, I did merge:

```
MERGE [dbo].[TestObjects] AS T_Base
USING #temp AS T_Source
ON (0<>0)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ([Hash],[Size],[Data]) VALUES (T_Source.[Hash],T_Source.[Size],T_Source.[Data])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], T_Source.[_oid];
```

If anyone have better approach - feel free to contribute to this answer.